# Set the color of a control in C++, Windows Store Metro App

Tags: c++, windows, colors, microsoft-metro

I'm making a Windows Store Metro application and I have some issues..

I want to set the color of a control in C++ but I can't figure out how to do it..

I have the following code now:

txt1->Background = ?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this C++/CLI or C++?

Comment: It's C++. We're making a WIndows Store Metro App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution, first make a brush object and set the color and assign that color to your controls background. I used the following:

```
SolidColorBrush^ myBrush = ref new SolidColorBrush(Windows::UI::Colors::Red);
TextBox^ txtID = ref new TextBox();
txtID->Background = myBrush;
```

Link to my question: [How to set a background color of a control in windows 8 store application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968550/how-to-set-a-background-color-of-a-control-in-windows-8-store-application)